# openlayers 3 icon offset and rotation

Tags: rotation, styles, openlayers, openlayers-3, offset

I have the following problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCAym.jpg.

JSFiddle added: https://jsfiddle.net/AJR80/phwq2v1k/

This is the code I use for the arrow... Rest can be seen in JSFiddle.

```
var style2 = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0, 0],
            anchorXUnits: "pixels",
            anchorYUnits: "pixels",
            offset: [0,0],
            offsetOrigin: 'bottom-left',
            src: 'https://i.imgur.com/YKy2qfG.png',
            rotation: 0
        }))
    });
```

In the pictures the arrow is one ol.Style.Icon, the "background image" with the white circle is another ol.Style.Icon and the text is ol.Style.Text. All have the same coordinates and I'm able to move text and background to the correct location on screen by using anchor-setting. The arrow is what makes me cry...

I can't use arrow's anchor since I want to rotate the arrow inside the background's white circle. If I try to change arrow's offset it will just cut the image.

I just want to move the "middle" to middle of the background's white circle. Can it be done? So far I haven't found a solution... Can someone help me to find it?

Much appreciated!

Antti

Answer (score 2):

Answer is here: https://jsfiddle.net/phwq2v1k/4/

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  updateWhileAnimating: true,
  updateWhileInteracting: true,
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    coords[0] += 2 * resolution;
    coords[1] += 17 * resolution;
    style2.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(coords));
    style2.getImage().setRotation(feature.get('rotation'));
    return styleArray;
  }
});
```